# Create a members address array in a struct

Tags: solidity, ether, arrays

I have the following struct:

```
struct Group {
    string name;
    address[] members;
}
```

and the following array:

```
Group[] public groups;
```

I don't need values, I only want to add one address after the next to check easier if a user is in a group or not (without creating another array and pointing that array to the struct).

Now I know, that for example groups[0].members[0] could be msg.sender.

Is there a way to create like only one way arrays, for example, that it is members[msg.sender] instead of members[0,1,273,37382...]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jaime thanks for your answer!

With your code I have found the solution I was looking for.
I wanted the members array right into the struct itself.
I edited the struct to the following:

```
struct Group {
    string name;
    mapping(address => bool) members; // <- ADDED THIS
}
```

Now I can do

> groups[0].members[msg.sender] = true;

and get

> if (groups[0].members[msg.sender] == true)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and that you solve it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I edited the whole answer after your explanation.

I think what you are looking for is a mapping. I understand that your concern is that the previous answer does not organize by groups, but you can have that order as follows:

```
mapping(string => mapping(address => bool)) public Groups;
```

If you want to know if a particular address lets say 0x12345 is in the group called "GroupA" just need to do as follows:

```
if (mapping['GroupA'][0x12345]){
  //it exists!!
}else{
 //do not exists 
}
```

The whole thing can be implemented as follows as follows:

```
contract CheckAddress{
 mapping(string => mapping(address => bool)) public Groups;

 function CheckAddress(){
  }

 function setAddresToGroup(address addr, string group) public {
   Groups[group][addr] = true; // set an addres in a group
 }

 function checkExistenceInGroup(address addr,string group) public returns (bool){
   return Groups[group][addr]; // will return true if the address is in group
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I know how to do it like you said, but tha's not how I would like to have it. That would create a huge array mapping. Instead I want for each group an own array like written in the main post.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by this: "Is there a way to create like only one way arrays, for example, that it is members[msg.sender] instead of members[0,1,273,37382...]?"

Comment: If I make an array like "address[] arrayName" I get values with calling arrayName[0], arrayName[1], arrayName[2],... etc. Those numbers than have the values, for example arrayName[0] could be "0x001...", arrayName[1] could be "0x123..." etc. But I want an array or other that has the address in the name itself. For example arrayName[0x001] or arrayName[0x123] etc. Because this would be easier to check. When I would check the first method I need to check each value if the address is the address I look for. In the second method I need only one check, if arrayName[msg.sender] exists.

Comment: I modified the answer for a complete description of how to do this. I hope this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I have added an answer like exactly how I wanted it. :)